# Выровнять картинку к тексту

Tags: html, css

Как сделать,чтобы начало текста было на уровне начала картинки,пытался изменить размеры картинки,но она сползает вниз

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приведите код этого блока.

Comment: текст и картинку в один блок